# tomcat one war file multiple web apps

Tags: tomcat

I have one war file that is being exploded once per web application.  This ends up using a lot of space for the same exact jars and classes but for different web applications.  In my case, here are two examples:

/usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/turnsmith.xml:

```
<Context docBase  = "${catalina.home}/wmsvision/vaadinwebsite.war"
    override      = "true"
    swallowOutput = "true"
    debug         = "0">

  <Parameter name = "socketType"
      override    = "false"
      value       = "Turnsmith" />
      <!-- value       = "WMSWebsite" /> -->
      <!-- value       = "WMSWebsite-NEWCUST2" /> -->

  <Parameter name="imageDirectory" override="false" value="/usr/local/tomcat/wmsvision/wmsImages" />

  <Parameter name="videoDirectory" override="false" value="/usr/local/tomcat/wmsvision/wmsVideos" />

  <Parameter name="wmsReports" override="false" value="/usr/local/tomcat/wmsvision/wmsReports" />

  <Parameter name = "debugCommand"
      override    = "false"
      value       = "true" />

  <Valve className = "org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
      prefix       = "turnsmith_access_log."
      suffix       = ".log"
      pattern      = "common"/>
</Context>
```

And then another referencing the exact same war file, /usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/vaadinwebsite.xml:

```
<Context docBase  = "${catalina.home}/wmsvision/vaadinwebsite.war"
    override      = "true"
    swallowOutput = "true"
    debug         = "0">

  <Parameter name = "socketType"
      override    = "false"
      value       = "WMSWebsite" />
      <!-- value       = "Turnsmith" /> -->
      <!-- value       = "WMSWebsite-NEWCUST2" /> -->

  <Parameter name="imageDirectory" override="false" value="/usr/local/tomcat/wmsvision/wmsImages" />

  <Parameter name = "debugCommand"
      override    = "false"
      value       = "true" />

  <Valve className = "org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
      prefix       = "vaadinwebsite_access_log."
      suffix       = ".log"
      pattern      = "common"/>
</Context>
```

This explodes as follows:

```
ls -ltd /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/turnsmith /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/vaadinwebsite 
drwxr-xr-x. 5 tomcat tomcat 4096 Jan  5 16:32 /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/vaadinwebsite
drwxr-xr-x. 5 tomcat tomcat 4096 Jan  5 16:32 /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/turnsmith

du -hs /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/turnsmith /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/vaadinwebsite
120M    /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/turnsmith
120M    /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/vaadinwebsite
```

Is there anyway to configure tomcat to more efficiently use the disk space?

As further information, the war file includes a bunch of library jars.  That is part of why they use so much space, I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a directory `$CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib`, put all your jars and edit `catalina.properties` to set `shared.loader` looks like this `shared.loader=$CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib`

In `catalina.properties` you can see how to configure the variable

```
#List of comma-separated paths defining the contents of the "shared"
# classloader. Prefixes should be used to define what is the repository type.
# Path may be relative to the CATALINA_BASE path or absolute. If left as blank,
# the "common" loader will be used as Catalina's "shared" loader.
# Examples:
#     "foo": Add this folder as a class repository
#     "foo/*.jar": Add all the JARs of the specified folder as class
#                  repositories
#     "foo/bar.jar": Add bar.jar as a class repository
```

Also you can put jars into the tomcat server library path `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`, but I recommend the first option

Comment: Ok, it is not seeing the shared loader.  You ever seen that?

Comment: I tried ${catalina.home} instead of $CATALINA_HOME, got the same problem.

Comment: Never mind, got it to work with following: shared.loader=${catalina.home}/shared/lib,${catalina.home}/shared/lib/*.jar

Comment: Happy to help. Consider also to mark the answer as correct if fits your question or upvote if it has been helpful

Comment: Yes, I was waiting to see if I ran into other problems.  I did, but that has nothing to do with your answer ( so far, at least ).  Marking now.